# Is there any way to redirect to a clean url when old url is requested?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to change the URLs on my website from `page.php?id=1&name=john` to `page/1/john` using htaccess RewriteRule.

This is what I have currently but it is not working as expected:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z\s-]+) page.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

Is it possible to make this change in htaccess rules or should I change every link to `<a href='page.php/1/john'>Page</a>` which is tiresome since I have got many links in every page. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please attach your htaccess in question

Comment: Also apart from what anubhava sir said, please mention clearly from which url to which url you want to redirect or rewrite in your question, thank you.

Comment: Why not chane href from `/page.php?id=1&name=john` to `/page/1/john`?

Comment: To be specific, when page.php?id=1&name=john is requested, I want to display /page/1/john on the address bar instead of page.php?id=1&name=john.

Comment: There are too many links and pages and it will take me some to change them all. It will be very much easier if there is an htaccess rule for that.

Comment: @Ammar, Basically we provide users USER FRIENDLY urls, in backend you could point them to complex(non user friendly) urls. So I believe you should give them `/page/1/john` one which will point further with query string in backend.

Comment: @Ammar, could you please check my answer once and let me know in its comments section how it goes?

Comment: It didn't work. My question is how do I go to /page/1/john when the user clicks on the link which is <a href='page.php?id=1&name=john'>Page</a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these 2 rules in site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rootfolder/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What I want was from the actual one to the clean one.

Comment: It is already there in this code. Test it out. First redirect rule will do `page.php?id=1&name=john` to `page/1/john`

Comment: @Ammar, its already there in anubhava sir's answer `# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one` AND in my 1st solution. You could test it and let both of us know then.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** To get from query string URL to user friendly url try following, as per OP's request.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rootfolder/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&name=([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\..*$ /$1/%1/%2/ [QSD,R=302,NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** As far as I get from OP's question, could you please try following. Considering as per thumb rule users will be given friendly URL like eg--> `http://localhost:80/page/1/john` and it will point in pointed to `http://localhost/page.php?id=1&name=john` in backend.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rootfolder/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2&name=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It is kind of working but it is taking me to localhost/page/1/john// instead of localhost/rootfolder/page/1/john.

Comment: @Ammar, it worked fine for me for shown samples. I made a slight change in regex, could you please check now 1st one and let me know then?

Comment: Still the same. When I type localhost/rootfolder/test.php?id=1&name=john , it is taking me to localhost/test/1/john

Comment: @Ammar, could you please try edited solution now? I have taken reference from anubhava sir's answer so added `RewriteBase` function from his nice solution, let me know. You could check his answer also, let us know then.

Comment: Yes. It finally worked after adding RewriteBase /rootfolder/ on first solution . Thank you so much. But what if the number of parameters is only 1 such as page.php?id=1 or page.php?name=john ?